# Find and xargs to correctly handle filenames with spaces in their names

Tags: linux, bash

Currently I use the following code to search and replace strings in any `.php` files under the current folder.

```
find . -name "*.php" -print | xargs sed -i 's/string1/string2/g'
```

But it throws an error as `No such file or directory` when it encounters a file with a space in its name. How would I modify this line to include files with spaces?

I would assume the output from the `find` command would have to output double quotes around the file path, but I don't know how to write that myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find . -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/string1/string2/g'
```

You can also do it without xargs at all:

```
find . -name "*.php" -execdir sed -i 's/string1/string2/g' {} +
```

Comment: `execdir` is preferred over `exec` to avoid race conditions, at least in GNU's implementation the manpages recommend the former.

Comment: @legends2k: you're right (at least for Linux which the OP seems to be using).  I updated my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you doing it at a part of your interactive work (not inside of some scripts - see limitations), you may find convient the following too:

```
shopt -s globstar  #best add to into ~/.bash_profile
sed -i 's/string1/string2/g' ./**/*.php
```

Limitation: the sum length of all your pathnames couldn't be longer as returns the `getconf ARG_MAX` command. On my system 262144 bytes - e.g. approx 6500 files like `./somedir/subdir/subsubdir/filename.php` - enough for usual interactive work...

Answer (score -1):

If you have GNU Parallel you can do this:

```
find . -name "*.php" -print | parallel -q sed -i 's/string1/string2/g'
```

This is useful if you want to process the file names before passing them to parallel. E.g. using `tail`:

```
find . -name "*.php" -print | tail -n 11 | parallel -q sed -i 's/string1/string2/g'
```

(-q is only needed if the strings contain special characters - such as space).

All new computers have multiple cores, but most programs are serial in nature and will therefore not use the multiple cores. However, many tasks are extremely parallelizeable:

- Run the same program on many files
- Run the same program for every line in a file
- Run the same program for every block in a file

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 883c667e01eed62f975ad28b6d50e22a
12345678 883c667e 01eed62f 975ad28b 6d50e22a
$ md5sum install.sh | grep cc21b4c943fd03e93ae1ae49e28573c0
cc21b4c9 43fd03e9 3ae1ae49 e28573c0
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep da012ec113b49a54e705f86d51e784ebced224fdf
79945d9d 250b42a4 2067bb00 99da012e c113b49a 54e705f8 6d51e784 ebced224
fdff3f52 ca588d64 e75f6033 61bd543f d631f592 2f87ceb2 ab034149 6df84a35
$ bash install.sh
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel